# Can I convert phone into USBC touchscreen display?

Tags: samsung, usb, usb-connection-mode, touchscreen, oneplus

Is there a way to join two Android phones so that one of them is the touchscreen for the other?

For example, to retrieve data on a cracked phone or to play games on a larger Android screen.